# iPhone Debugger Message -- Weird

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have an iPhone app that I've been working on and have recently upgraded my version of XCode.  Since the upgrade, I can build and debug in the iPhone Simulator just fine, but when I try to debug on an attached device I get the following messages:

**From Xcode4:**

```
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1510) (Fri Oct 22 04:12:10 UTC 2010)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "--host=i386-apple-darwin --target=arm-apple-darwin".tty /dev/ttys001
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
warning: Unable to read symbols from "dyld" (prefix __dyld_) (not yet mapped into memory).
warning: Unable to read symbols for (null)/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI (file not found).
warning: Unable to read symbols from "MessageUI" (not yet mapped into memory).
warning: Unable to read symbols for (null)/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/MapKit (file not found).
warning: Unable to read symbols from "MapKit" (not yet mapped into memory).
warning: Unable to read symbols from "Foundation" (not yet mapped into memory).
warning: Unable to read symbols for (null)/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit (file not found).
warning: Unable to read symbols from "UIKit" (not yet mapped into memory).
warning: Unable to read symbols for (null)/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics (file not found).
warning: Unable to read symbols from "CoreGraphics" (not yet mapped into memory).
warning: Unable to read symbols from "CoreData" (not yet mapped into memory).
warning: Unable to read symbols from "QuartzCore" (not yet mapped into memory).
warning: Unable to read symbols from "libgcc_s.1.dylib" (not yet mapped into memory).
warning: Unable to read symbols from "libSystem.B.dylib" (not yet mapped into memory).
warning: Unable to read symbols from "libobjc.A.dylib" (not yet mapped into memory).
warning: Unable to read symbols from "CoreFoundation" (not yet mapped into memory).
target remote-mobile /tmp/.XcodeGDBRemote-3836-28
Switching to remote-macosx protocol
mem 0x1000 0x3fffffff cache
mem 0x40000000 0xffffffff none
mem 0x00000000 0x0fff none
[Switching to thread 11523]
[Switching to thread 11523]
gdb stack crawl at point of internal error:
0   gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x0013216e internal_vproblem + 316
```

Comment: What iOS version is installed on the device? Also, XCode 4 is not stable and probably not yet meant for on-device testing. Either way, weird errors are to be expected when using beta software for testing on the device.

Comment: The same thing happens in XCode 3.  4.2.1 is installed on the phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like there was a problem linking to your frameworks library.  try and remove the references and relink them.  FYI - do not copy into project as that can cause other problems.